# How to import a module that isn't in the same folder?

Tags: python, import, module, directory

I'm having problem with a project, in order to organize it I'm subdividing it into diferentes folders and I'm not getting import a module that are in a different folder. Anyone knows how can I resolve this trouble ?

Comment: There are already many, _many_ questions in Stack Overflow about Python imports. For example, have you looked at [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4383571/16775594)? Please show your research effort in your question. See [ask] and the [help] for more information on asking good questions.

Answer (score -1):

Use `import folder.modulename`. This should work